# get Method annotation with javassist

Tags: java, spring, javassist

is it possible to get Spring method annotation with javassist in this example ?

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/start"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET})
public String showForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
 import javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation;
    :
 CtMethod m = ... ;
 MethodInfo minfo = m.getMethodInfo();
 AnnotationsAttribute attr = (AnnotationsAttribute)
         minfo.getAttribute(AnnotationsAttribute.invisibleTag);
 Annotation an = attr.getAnnotation("Author");
 String s = ((StringMemberValue)an.getMemberValue("name")).getValue();
 System.out.println("@Author(name=" + s + ")");
```

from official document: https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/bytecode/AnnotationsAttribute.html

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand the question, you could retrive it using Java reflection.

**If you know the method and the annotation:**

```
RequestMapping annotation = YourController.class.getMethod("showForm", Model.class, HttpServletRequest.class).getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

RequestMethod[] requestMethods = annotation.method();
```

**If you want to retrive all the annotations on a specific method:**

```
Annotation[] annotations = YourController.class.getMethod("showForm", Model.class, HttpServletRequest.class).getAnnotations();
```

**If you want to retrieve all the methods with the given annotation:**

```
List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Method method : YourController.class.getMethods()) {
    if (method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class) != null) {
        methods.add(method);
    }
}
```

or Java 8 way:

```
List<Method> methods = Arrays.stream(YourController.class.getMethods()).filter(method -> method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class) != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```